# Angular: Actualizar opción seleccionada de un select options con búsqueda usando reactive forms

Tags: bootstrap, angular

Tengo un conjunto de botones cada uno representa una opción de un listado de selección con búsqueda y lo que quiero conseguir es que al hacer click en algún botón dicha opción se seleccione en el listado. Sería como una especie de filtro o atajo para elegir una opción del listado.

Al hacer click en cada uno de los botones y desplegar la lista se selección la opción y el valor de la forma va cambiando pero no se cambia la leyenda del input. Es un problema de visualización.

Agradecería enormemente si alguien puede ayudarme a encontrar cuál es el problema y como corregirlo. Soy nueva usando angular así que pido disculpas de antemano si estoy cometiendo algún error de principiante pero ya intentado de todo y no he podido solucionarlo.

Si utilizo un listado de selección común funciona perfectamente pero necesito lograr este comportamiento con un listado de selección con búsqueda ya que lo utilizaré mucho en este proyecto.

Muchas gracias!

Estoy usando Angular 8, Bootstrap v4.3.1, bootstrap-select v.1.13.9 (https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

- formularioreactivo.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-formularioreactivo',
  templateUrl: './formularioreactivo.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class FormularioreactivoComponent {

  forma: FormGroup;

  zonas: any[] = [
    {
      codigo: 1,
      zona: 'zona 1',
    },
    {
      codigo: 2,
      zona: 'zona 2',
    },
    {
      codigo: 3,
      zona: 'zona 3',
    },
    {
      codigo: 4,
      zona: 'zona 4',
    },
    {
      codigo: 5,
      zona: 'zona 5',
    },
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.forma = new FormGroup({
      zona: new FormControl(this.zonas[2] ),
    });
    }

    recargarZona( zona: any ) {
      this.forma.setValue({ zona });
    }

}
```

- formularioreactivo.component.html

```js
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <button *ngFor="let zona of zonas" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="recargarZona(zona)"> {{ zona.zona }} </button>
</div>


<form [formGroup]="forma" class="mt-5">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" formControlName="zona">
        <option *ngFor="let zona of zonas" [ngValue]="zona">
            {{ zona.zona }}
        </option>
    </select>
</form>

<br>

<p>Form value: {{ forma.value | json }}</p>
```

- app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormularioreactivoComponent } from './components/formularioreactivo/formularioreactivo.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FormularioreactivoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: El plugin que mencionas requiere jQuery y tu estas usando Angular

Comment: Gracias por responder. El listado de selección con búsqueda funciona. Lo que no logro solucionar es que al hacer click en un botón se visualice alguna de las opciones del listado.

Comment: Porque esas opciones no son las de tu `select`, al que está enlazado el formulario, sino a elementos dinamicos generados por tu plugin. Esto es fácil de entender si sabes que estilar un elemento `select` es casi imposible por lo que hay que simular su apariencia usando elementos regulares. Eso es lo que hacen todos los plugins que generan select customizados.

Comment: Claro ahora entiendo. Tendrías alguna sugerencia de como lograr el comportamiento que necesito o  de plano no podré conseguirlo usando select customizados y angular ?

Comment: honestamente creo que deberías cambiar a Material. Las librerías que usan bootstrap no han podido mantener el ritmo de evolución de Angular. Aquí tienes un ejemplo del componente que necesitas https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#adding-a-custom-filter

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por responder! Voy a tener en cuenta tu recomendación.

Comment: Buen día! Yo realice una simulación de tu código y al hacer click en un botón perfectamente se cambia la opción en el <p> y también el placeholder del dropdown. Si quizás instalaste alguno de los paquetes de bootstrap mientras aun estabas ejecutando el proyecto... cancélalo y vuelve a correr ng serve.

Comment: Buen día Sergio! En la prueba que hiciste, usaste el plugin bootstrap-select ? porque con un listado de selección normal también me funciona perfectamente. El problema es con este tipo de plugin.

Answer (score -1):

No estoy seguro si es lo que buscas, pero he echo una prueba y sin importar donde hago los cambios, tanto con botones como con el listado de los datos en el `<p>` se cambian. Lo que descubrí, es que en tu `app.modules.ts` no hay esto:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Al probar cuando lo borro, el comportamiento cambia, y no funciona correctamente.

Answer (score -1):

tu variable `forma` es un `FormGroup` debes buscar el `FormControl` dentro y actualizar el valor

```
recargarZona( zona: any ) {
   this.forma.get('zona').setValue(zona);
}
```